# Как отбросить цветовую информацию пикселей

Tags: java, android, bitmap, color

В [данной статье](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/122372/) говорится, что "...цветовые характеристики изображения оказывают гораздо меньшее влияние на визуальные ощущения схожести изображений по сравнению с яркостными, потому их можно отбросить".

Насколько я понял, нужно преобразовать изображение в градацию серого, чтобы каждый серый пиксель хранил только яркостную характеристику, то есть условно говоря от 0 - абсолютно черный до 1 - абсолютно белый. Вопрос состоит в том как получить яркость каждого серого пикселя.

Есть функция, преобразующая bitmap в оттенки серого:

```
private Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

То есть просто убирается saturation на 0. При этом значение которое возвращает `bitmap.getPixel(x, y)` после преобразования не изменяется для пикселей.

Как найти яркостную характеристику для каждого пикселя, отбросив при этом цветовую информацию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Часто используют такую формулу:

```
Gray = (Red * 0.3 + Green * 0.59 + Blue * 0.11)
```

Ещё есть формула BT.709 (Luma):

```
Gray = (Red * 0.2126 + Green * 0.7152 + Blue * 0.0722)
```

И еще есть BT.601 (почти равна первой):

```
Gray = (Red * 0.299 + Green * 0.587 + Blue * 0.114)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Только у меня еще получилось его добыть так: `float[] hsv = new float[3];` `for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            Color.colorToHSV(colors[i], hsv);` `hsv[2] }` это в пределах 0..1 получается